# Accidently sent ERC 20 tokens to an ETH address on Binance

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I made a mistake as the wrong address was in my clipboard. Will I lose my tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of address it was and who owns it.

If the wrong address is your own wallet, for example one you created using Metamask, Mist, Parity, Ethereum Wallet, geth or MyEtherWallet, then your tokens can be retrieved from the wallet you created the address in.

If the wrong address belongs to someone else, you could ask them to send your tokens back. For example, if it was the deposit address of an exchange or other service, you can contact their customer support and ask them to send the tokens back.

If the wrong address was a smart contract that has nothing to do with these type of tokens, then they are most likely lost.